# How i can create a function which analize text in rows in 1 columns and rewrite in others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example - i have smth like this

all info in 1 column

|  | header | Company | price | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | done |  |  |  |
| 2 | nan |  |  |  |
| 3 | comp1 |  |  |  |
| 4 | nan |  |  |  |
| 5 | price:222 |  |  |  |
| 6 | result:ok, 22.05.19 |  |  |  |
| 7 | nan |  |  |  |
| 8 | done |  |  |  |
| 9 | nan |  |  |  |
| 10 | comp2 |  |  |  |
| 11 | nan |  |  |  |
| 12 | price:2895 |  |  |  |
| 13 | result:no, 15.05.19 |  |  |  |
| 14 | nan |  |  |  |
| 15 | done |  |  |  |
| 16 | and ctr |  |  |  |

i try to find ot how to creat a function that will put info in other columns
the right result
header 1

| num | Company | price | result | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Comp1 | 222 | ok | 22.05.19 |
| 2 | Comp2 | 2895 | no | 15.05.19 |
| etc |  |  |  |  |

Comment: How do you generate this DataFrame? it's likely better to start from scratch

Comment: What is and ctr and the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best idea is likely to import the data correctly from the beginning.

That said, and mostly for fun, you can fix this format using a regex and reshaping:

```
# remove NaNs, and "done" rows
s = df['header'].loc[df['header'].ne('done')].dropna()

# extract the Price/Result/Date
pattern = r'price:(?P<Price>\d+)|result:(?P<Result>\w+), (?P<Date>[\d.]+)'
df2 = s.str.extract(pattern)

# identify potential company names
m = df2.isna().all(axis=1)

# reshape
out = (df2
    .assign(Company=s.where(m))
    .set_index(m.cumsum(), append=True)
    .droplevel(0)
    .stack().unstack()
    .dropna(subset=['Price', 'Result', 'Date'], how='all')
)
```

Output:

```
  Price Result      Date Company
1   222     ok  22.05.19   comp1
2  2895     no  15.05.19   comp2
```

Comment: good use of `str.extract` +1. I made an answer from your good idea

Comment: Thank u. great decision, but at the end there is :
    .dropna(subset=['Price', 'Result', 'Date'], how='all')
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @Alish I think you forgot to copy the last `)`

Comment: oh yep than u . And i have a question,please, If i have not date like date: 25.02.2021, if it look like --   date: 17:59, 15 December 2021.

Comment: Then in place of `(?P<Date>[\d.]+)` use `(?P<Date>.+)`

Answer (score 0):

I can see the company, status, dates position have pattern with price. If it the same with your actual data, you can do as below:

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'header':['done', None, 'comp1', None, 'price:222', 'result:ok, 22.05.19', None, 'Done', None,
                           'comp2', None, 'price:2895',  'result:no, 15.05.19', None, 'Done', 'and ctr'],'Company':None, 'price':None, 'data':None})
```

Code:

```
ls=list(df.header.str.split(':')) 
pd.DataFrame([{'Company':ls[i-2][0], 'price': v[1], 'result': ls[i+1][1].split(',')[0], 'date':ls[i+1][1].split(',')[1]} 
                                   for i, v in enumerate(ls) if 'price'in str(v)])
```

Output:

```
   Company  price   result  date
0   comp1   222     ok      22.05.19
1   comp2   2895    no      15.05.19
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answer made with mozway's good idea.

**Example**

```
data = ['done', None, 'comp1', None, 'price:222', 'result:ok, 22.05.19', None, 
        'done', None, 'comp2', None, 'price:2895','result:no, 15.05.19', None, 'done']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['header'])
```

`df`

```
    header
0   done
1   None
2   comp1
3   None
4   price:222
5   result:ok, 22.05.19
6   None
7   done
8   None
9   comp2
10  None
11  price:2895
12  result:no, 15.05.19
13  None
14  done
```

---

**Code**

```
pattern = r'(?P<Company>comp\d)|price:(?P<Price>\d+)|result:(?P<Result>\w+), (?P<Date>[\d.]+)'
grouper = df['header'].str.contains('^comp').cumsum()
out = (df['header'].str.extract(pattern).groupby(grouper).first()
       .dropna(subset=['Company']).set_index('Company'))
```

`out`

```
        Price   Result  Date
Company         
comp1   222     ok      22.05.19
comp2   2895    no      15.05.19
```